# django-registration + ajax, user_registered signal randomly fails

Tags: ajax, django, django-registration, django-signals

I have "successfully" integrated django-registration with ajax in my project.

I'm using the user_registered signal to add additional information to the user upon registering.

Everything works whenever I test it personally. However, when I checked django-admin to see how many users have registered, I noticed that some users were created with only the default fields and does not include the fields created with the signal callback.

Is there a known reason why a django signal would fail?

Here's my user_registered callback:

```
def user_registered_callback(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    # Create a new instance of Registration form and bind the POST data
    form = CustomRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    form.full_clean()

    # Generate new filename from timestamp and first name
    fn = hashlib.md5()
    fn.update( str(time.time()) + form.cleaned_data['first_name'] )
    filename = fn.hexdigest() + '.jpg'

    # Save additional details for the user
    u = user
    u.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
    u.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
    u.birthdate = form.cleaned_data['birthdate']
    u.mobile = form.cleaned_data['mobile']
    u.photo = 'photos/' +  filename
    u.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

The user_registered signal is a custom signal introduced by django-registration, therefore I assume it would not be triggered if you use Django's original admin site. Also why should it be triggered, since adding a user in the admin is not a user registering himself.

Try registering your handler for post_save of your user class instead:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.pk:
        # instance was just created
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear in my question. The new users were created using the django-registration implementation I did using ajax. I just used django-admin to check how many users have actually registered.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally replicated the error and traced through Developer tools what it was.

As it turned out some users were adding strings to `first_name` that are longer than the maximum I set for that field in the database. However, I wasn't able to add a `Form` validation for this field that's why it was able to get past my form as valid. Hence, the app was able to create a new user, but when it comes to updating the `user_profile` it fails making it look like the signal callback didn't run.